# How can I add a delay to a button in Polymer?

Tags: html, css, polymer

I've stated creating a Polymer-based webpage and I'd like to add a link to the `paper-button` I created. I've figured out how to do it, but I'd like to add a delay to let users see the ripple animation after clicking it.

To link it to a webpage I used this code:

```
<a href="http://www.google.it"> <paper-button raised> Polymer's Website </paper-button> </a>
```

However, I don't know how to add a delay. Could someone help me? And, is there a better way to link the button to a webpage?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an element that extends native HTML `a` tag and use paper-ripple element if you want to customize the ripple effect. Another solution is to add an event to you paper-button and use a setTimeout to delay your action

```js
goto:function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
             window.location.href = 'http:\\www.google.com';
             },1000);
  
 }
```

```html
<paper-button raised on-click="goto"> Polymer's Website </paper-button>
```

Comment: I can't manage to get it work. Even if I copied the script instead of rewriting. Here's the code: `<paper-button raised on-click="goto"> Polymer's Website </paper-button>
        
        <script>
            
            goto:function(){
                
                setTimeout(function(){
                    
                    window.location.href = 'http:\\www.google.com';
                    
                    },500);
  
            }
            
        </script>`